# Variance-Covariance Matrix (Sphericity): Valid?

Tags: anova, variance, repeated-measures, covariance-matrix, sphericity

I am completing a basic statistics exercise for a graduate-level ANOVA course (for psychology trainees). We've just started on repeated measures (i.e. within-subjects) designs, beginning with the simplest scenario: a single factor.

In our tutorial, a visual test for sphericity has been demonstrated with the use of a variance-covariance matrix. The following covariance matrix has been presented as part of the exercise I am completing:
[image: Table 1.]

This covariance matrix represents a single factor (three levels) repeated measures design. The assumption of sphericity is said to be met when, "the variances of the differences between all pairs of conditions [i.e. factor levels] are equal." In this example, we can express this as:

$$\sigma^2_{{j_1}-j_{2}} =\, \sigma^2_{{j_1}-j_{3}} = \sigma^2_{{j_2}-j_{3}}$$

Implicit here is that this the ideal situation, and inferential tests for sphericity do not assume exact equivalence, but rather approximate equivalence in the variance of the differences.

The variance of a difference is given by:

$${\sigma^2_{j-k}= \sigma^2_j + \sigma^2_k - 2\sigma_{jk}}$$

When I apply this formula for the case of $\sigma^2_{j_1-j_2}$, I obtain an interesting result. So plugging in the numbers, we have:

$\sigma^2_{j_1-j_2} = 4 + 10 - 2(11) = 14 - 22 = -8$

My understanding is that the variance of a set cannot be less than zero. I'm inclined to say that the covariance matrix that has been supplied in this exercise is invalid (i.e. impossible). Unless I am missing something?

Comment: You are correct: this matrix is not positive-definite and therefore is not a covariance matrix.  One demonstration is that its determinant (equal to $-387$) is negative.  Another demonstration is to show it implies the variance of some linear combination of the variables would be negative--and that's what you have shown.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful.